# Can a VLAN managed Switch connect via LAN to a router and establish a second isolated network?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, switch, vlan

Setup is:

A main router, then a VLAN capable, manageable Switch with different LAN ports. Connecting this Switch via LAN cable to a LAN port of the main router. The Switche's goal is to establish a separated network for connected additional guest devices (isolate them from the devices connected with the main router's WiFI).

If guests connect to the Switch via LAN would the guest's devices be able to "interact" with the devices connected to the WIFI of the main router? Could there be any kind of interaction on Layer 2 or 3?

If this setup does not fulfill the "isolation" criteria, what additional setting changes are needed (on the main router or the Switch) to achieve isolation between Switch Devices & Main Router devices - and how to do these changes?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit ambiguous - hopefully this helps:

VLANs only operate at layer 2. This means that if the router is so configured (and this is fairly typical), clients behind separate VLANs can communicate with each other by routing packets via the router. This assumes subnets and IP addresses allow this behaviour.

There are different types of VLAN ports - tagged, untagged and hybrid ports.  In a typical simple setup you would have multiple tagged ports (or a trunk) on the router LAN interface the switch connects to, and these also configured as tagged/trunk ports on the switch. You would typically then have untagged ports on the switch associated with the VLAN you want the end device to be on.

VLANs work in conjunction with subnets and routing.

(If you are still trying to solve the isolating WLAN and Ethernet problem you keep posting about, this method requires a **better router** and a **higher understanding of networking** then the solutions already proposed.  )